# Can not open Google blog webpage in WebControl in C#

Tags: c#, load, webbrowser-control

I am trying to display a Google Blog webpage in WebControl.

With the page index (http://googlefrance.blogspot.fr/)  it' OKs. With page Blog (eg. http://googlefrance.blogspot.fr/2012/08/elle-est-arrivee-la-nexus-7-est.html), I got black page with no content.

```
namespace TestLoadGoogleBlogPage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowserGoogleBlog.Navigate("http://googlefrance.blogspot.com/"); // OK
            // KO webBrowserGoogleBlog.Navigate("http://googlefrance.blogspot.com/2012/08/elle-est-arrivee-la-nexus-7-est.html");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully loaded the page with [Watin](http://watin.org/)

```
using (var WatiNbrowserIE = new WatinCore.IE("http://googlefrance.blogspot.fr/2012/08/elle-est-arrivee-la-nexus-7-est.html"))
{
   while (!WatiNbrowserIE.Elements.Exists(WatinCore.Find.ByClass("article-content entry-content"))) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); }
   string sTitle = WatiNbrowserIE.Elements.Filter(WatinCore.Find.ByClass("title entry-title")).First().Text;

   // Some code here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be javascript related. If you try to open that webpage http://googlefrance.blogspot.com/2012/08/elle-est-arrivee-la-nexus-7-est.html without javascript enabled in a browser it shows blank.

So the issue isn't in your program, since webcontrol can't handle javascript, it is the webpage you are trying to access.